# Avoiding repeated questions using AMC package

Tags: auto-multiple-choice

I'm trying to write a Latex source file to create my first exam in AMC. However, my Latex file is producing copies with repeated questions and I couldn't find out how to solve that reading the official manual. I'd be very grateful if anyone could help me. Thanks in advance!

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{automultiplechoice} 

\begin{document} 

\setdefaultgroupmode{withoutreplacement} %I thought this could solve the problem!?

\begin{examcopy}[10] 
\cleargroup{finalgroup} 

\element{group01}{
\begin{question}{group01q01} Analysis
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\element{group01}{
\begin{question}{group01q02} Algebra
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\element{group01}{
\begin{question}{group01q03} Geometry
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\shufflegroup{group01} 
\copygroup[2]{group01}{finalgroup} 

\element{group02}{
\begin{question}{group02q01} Verbs
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\element{group02}{
\begin{question}{group02q02} Pronouns
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\element{group02}{
\begin{question}{group02q03} Adjectives
    \begin{choices} 
        \correctchoice{Correct choice}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (1)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (2)}
        \wrongchoice{Wrong choice (3)}
    \end{choices}
\end{question}
}

\shufflegroup{group02} 
\copygroup[2]{group02}{finalgroup} 

\shufflegroup{finalgroup}
\insertgroup{finalgroup}

\end{examcopy}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was about the order of the instructions of the document. At the beginning of the document, we write

```
\setdefaultgroupmode{withoutreplacement}
```

indeed. Then, we describe the "base" groups. Only after all the groups are written, we begin the "examcopy" environment, in which we create the "final group", shuffle groups, transfer questions from the base groups to the final group and insert the final group, that is, the questionnaire.